# Проверка первых сообщений, с учётом новых правил

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, аудит

Только что был в очереди проверок и наткнулся на следующий проверочный вопрос

---

### javascript задачка

Вычислите √(x - √y), если x и y вводит пользователь. Перед вычислением выполнить проверку на существование квадратных корней.

[javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

---

В связи с недавними изменениями, где учебные вопросы возможно задавать без попытки решить их самостоятельно - нажал кнопку "**Действие не требуется**" на что получил сообщение:

*СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.

Данная проверка была нужна для того, чтобы оценить вашу внимательность. Вы не прошли проверку. Качество сообщения очень низкое, в него необходимо внести значительные корректировки, чтобы оно стало полезным — игнорирование подобных сообщений мешает другим участникам находить хорошие вопросы и отвечать на них. Пожалуйста, постарайтесь исправлять такие сообщения с помощью редактирования, голосования «против», закрытия или оставляя отметку «очень низкое качество».*

*Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста, уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые инструкции.*

---

Отсюда вопрос, что именно по текущим правилам в этом вопросе не так, и на что влияет количество не пройденных проверок?

Comment: Это очень интересный и важный вопрос. В очередях проверок бывают неочевидные проверки, которые не угадаешь как правильно ответить (и часто бывало, что эти конкретные проверки переделывались), но тут похоже действительно из-за изменения правил (которые пока в статусе "эксперимента", а значит, гипотетически могут быть отменены по результатам) гипотетически не исключено, что у нас нужно будет отключать все проверки или переделывать. Надо подумать, не готов так сходу рекомендовать какой-то конкретный рецепт.

Comment: @AK, мне кажется, был какой-то механизм то ли у модераторов, то ли у КМ по исключению вопросов из списка контрольных. Нужно им воспользоваться и он больше не будет использоваться для проверки внимательности аудиторов.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Мне тоже так казалось раньше, но насколько я понимаю сейчас -- его нет. То есть допустим, на уровне одного вопроса типа спам-не спам -- нужно заходить в вопрос, снимать флаг спама зря поставленный. А чтобы на уровне всех вопросов, да не про спам, а про правильно ли закрыт... надо уточнить у коллег, есть или нет подобное.

Comment: Вопрос-то слишком общий в любом случае, независимо от его учебности

Comment: @andreymal, мне не кажется что он общий, тут просится о решение в явном виде, ранее такие сообщения без попыток автором решить не пропускались, теперь пропускаются. А так вроде все понятно что хотел автор вопроса. Или нет? Вот мне не совсем понятно что именно не так в текущей обстановке.

Comment: @PotroNik а мне кажется. С чем именно требуется помощь — с вводом, с математическими вычислениями, с выводом? Это как минимум три разных вопроса.

Comment: Я бы однозначно закрыл, потому что сам вопрос не озвучен в тексте задачи. Без разницы: домашка студента, или текущая задача передового  специалиста РосКосмоса.

Comment: А ещё не знаю как тут, но иногда математические вычисления можно ещё разделить на два вопроса: выяснение принципиального алгоритма решения задачи и запись этого алгоритма в коде на нужном ЯП. В общем, четыре разных вопроса :)